# Positive semi-definite matrix and the tempered distribution $e^{-\frac{\langle A x, x\rangle}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A \in M_{n \times n}( C )$. I want to show that the function $e^{-\frac{\langle A x, x\rangle}{2}}$ is in $S(\Bbb R^n)'$ (via the integration) if and only if $\operatorname{Re} A$ is semi-positive. However, it seems too difficult to me. I cannot even cross the first step to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big hint: If $\langle \text{Re} A x_0, x_0\rangle <0$ for some $x_0$, decompose $\mathbb{R}^n$ into the line through $x_0$ and it's orthogonal complement. Then use Fubini's theorem with this decomposition with a test function $\psi\in \mathcal{S}$ that decays like $e^{-|x|^a}$ for some $0<a<2$.